# Angular variable declared in jade is undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, pug

I made a simple html page which made use of angular. The navigation menu contains 3 links. Angular's ng-click is used to set visibility true or false for the three divs that represent the pages (or views). In html it works fine, but I needed to add some other features which made me convert it into jade. However, the values inside ng-click are now undefined. Below are both versions of the code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="" ng-click="view_one=true; view_two=false; view_three=false">First page</a></li>
            <li><a href="" ng-click="view_one=false; view_two=true; view_three=false">Second page</a></li>
            <li><a href="" ng-click="view_one=false; view_two=false; view_three=true">Third page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController" ng-show='view_one'>
 Content 1
</div>

<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController" ng-show='view_two'>
 Content 2
</div>

<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController" ng-show='view_three'>
 Content 3
</div>
```

Jade:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
  .navbar-centre
    ul.nav.navbar-nav
      li
        a(href='', ng-click='view_one=true; view_two=false; view_three=false') First page
      li
        a(href='', ng-click='view_one=false; view_two=true; view_three=false') Second page
      li
        a(href='', ng-click='view_one=false; view_two=false; view_three=true') Third page

.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_one')
 Content one
.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_two')
Content two
.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_three')
 Content three
```

Normally the syntax for contents is not as in the code. The three views display correctly, but they don't hide / show when the menu is clicked. Also when I print any of the variables (ex view_one), it seems that the value is undefined

Comment: Are you sure is not something related to indentation in Jade? The code you posted does not seem properly indented...

Comment: I dont think there is a problem with indentation because: 1) when there was some problem with indentation,trying to open the page would give me an error. In this case there are no errors, only undefined values.  2) Just to be sure I also tried a version of jade that I got from converting html online. It may or may not be correct, but I got the same exact result as the one when I wrote it myself.

Comment: Ok, so I guess "Content two" not indented in the code you posted is just some wrong copy/paste here, right?

Comment: As i stated earlier, the content here is dummy content , replaced so that the code looks neater and more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
html(ng-app="myApp")
  body
nav.navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
  div
    ul.nav.navbar-nav
      li
        a(href="",ng-click='view_one=true; view_two=false; view_three=false') First page
      li
        a(href="",ng-click='view_one=false; view_two=true; view_three=false') Second page
      li
        a(href="",ng-click='view_one=false; view_two=false; view_three=true') Third page
.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_one')
  | Content 1
.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_two')
  | Content 2
.container(ng-controller='mainController', ng-show='view_three')
  | Content 3
```

With dummy JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("mainController", function() {});
```

See jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/kahinog/edit?html,js,output).
I think there's something wrong in the code you did not paste...maybe you can prepare and provide a jsbin?

Comment: Thanks, I see that this code actually works. However when I copy paste it into my environment and change only the app name (my app is called differently), it does not work again. I think that the mistake is not with jade then, but with the way that js files are included.